# 15 dice, chances of getting three either 1 or 4

Tags: probability

I have 15 dice, by rolling three either 1 or 4 can win me the game. It doesn't have to be three 1's or three 4's, it could also be 1-1-4 or 1-4-4, etc. As long as I have three 1 or 4, I will win the game.

What is the probability of me losing the game?

I know the total outcome of rolling 15 dice is 6^15. I tried to simplify the question by just rolling 2 dice, total outcome is 6^2 = 36. Drew a table to list all 36 possible outcomes and counted the cases with at least a 1 or 4, and the probability of such case is 20/36 = 55%.

But I just don't know the proper way to deal with this question without drawing the table out.

Thank you!

P.S.
To clarify my question, here is an example.
Let say you have 15 dices, and you roll them all at once. Afterwards, you look at each dice and see if it is either 1 or 4. If it is, then you add a point to the scoreboard. If it's not, then your score remains the same. Your score starts at 0. The goal is to get 3 points, and you will win the game.
So, what is the probability of losing the game? Meaning after looking at all 15 dices, your score is 2 or less.
I think Bruce has already answered the question, but I added this for extra clarification just in case.

Comment: Mouse : Mice :: Die : Dice. Edited.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it's binomial. Success is 1 or 4, Failure is anything else. So P(Success) = 1/3 on any one die. You lose if you get 2 or fewer Successes in n=15 trials. In R, (where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF), `pbinom(2, 15, 1/3)` returns  0.07935712. // You can get the same answer by using the binomial PDF for 0, 1, and 2. // If it's not that simple, please edit your problem to explain.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, Bruce! I have added more explanation to the situation described for more clarity, although I think that you are already understanding the question correctly.
I am wondering, without the help from R, can I still achieve the answer by using pen and paper?

Comment: You're right that your addendum does not change my understanding of the problem. // Once again it's _one die, two dice._ 'Dices' might refer to a cook chopping onions into small pieces. // I think your assignment might be to use 'pen and paper' (and maybe a callculator) with the formula for a binomial PDF to get $P(X=0)+P(X=1) + P(X=2) = 0.0794.$ I have purposely avoided doing that because this is not a 'do my homework' site and you need to do it for yourself. Maybe you have studied normal aprox to binomial and that would be an acceptable method for your course; if so, again your job.

Answer (score 5):

**Comment** continued with a simulation of a million such games in R. The simulated answer
$0.0791 \pm 0.0005$ matches the exact answer in my Comment to three places.

```
set.seed(804)
m = 10^6; s = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  x = sample(1:6, 15, rep=T)
  s[i] = sum(x==1)+sum(x==3) }
mean(s <= 2)
[1] 0.079097      # aprx P(Lose) = 0.07936
2*sd(s <= 2)/1000
[1] 0.0005397805  # aprx 95% margin of simulation error
```

The histogram bars show simulated values of $\mathsf{Binom}(15, 1/3)$
and the red dots show exact binomial probabilities.

```
hist(s, prob=T, br = (-.5:15.5), col="skyblue2")
k=0:15; pdf=dbinom(k,15,1/3)
 points(k, pdf, col="red", pch=19)
```

[image]

The figure below adds the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = np, \sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}),$ where $n = 15, p = 1/3,$ which approximates your
binomial distribution.

[image]

We can get a reasonable approximation to $P(X \le 2) = P(X \le 2.5) \approx 0.0856$ by
using this normal distribution. Normally, you shouldn't expect more than two places of accuracy from a normal approximation, unless $n$ is large or $p$ is near $1/2$ or both. (The normal approximation is not as
close to the truth as is the simulation above.)

```
mu = 15/3;  mu
[1] 5
sg = sqrt(2*mu/3); sg
[1] 1.825742
dnorm(2.5, mu, sg)
[1] 0.08556962
```

You can standardize and use printed normal tables to get about this same
answer from the normal approximation. (It will be a little different because
some rounding is necessary when using printed tables.)